# $d^2=r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ geometric interpretation.

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, vectors, polar-coordinates

> If two points have polar coordinates $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2)$ show that the distance $d$ between them is given by:
> $d^2 = r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$.

This question from Spivak calculus book, I solve it by work on the Cartesian coordinates, I did $x = r_1 \cos(\theta_1)$ and $x' = r_2 \cos(\theta_2)$ and the same work with $y$, this is not difficult.

Now, when I did find
$d^2 = r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$,
I saw something in this equation. If we imagine $r_1$ and $r_2$ as a norms of vectors $v$ and $w$, then
$$ 
d^2 = \|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2 
- 2\|v\|\|w\| \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) 
= v \cdot v + w \cdot w - 2 v \cdot w. 
$$
(${}\cdot{}$ scalar product) so with some manipulation we will get $d = \| v - w \|$.

**So my geometric interpretation is as follows: the new vector $v-w$ is always one that starts from the end of the vector $v$ to the end of the vector $w$.**

(Also I noticed that this equation give to us the general formula for $\cos(\theta)$ on term of the three sides, for any triangle.)

My simple question is: Is my interpretation right?.

Comment: Looks good! Did you use al-Kashi's [Law of Cosines](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_cosines) to arrive at the original expression for $d^2$?

Comment: for  the original expression i did just  use tha cartesian coordinate system ,by putting $x = r_1 \cos(\theta_1)$ and $x' = r_2 \cos(\theta_2)$  ,$y = r_1 \sin(\theta_1)$ and $y' = r_2 \sin(\theta_2)$ and we know the difference d between the points $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ is $\sqrt{((x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}$ so directly after replace this variable you will get the  original expression

Comment: I see. But notice also that if you draw a triangle whose vertices are the origin and the head of the arrows for $v$ and $w$, and $\theta = \theta_1 - \theta_2$ is the interior angle at the origin, then the formula is precisely the Law of Cosines.